# Microphone noise cancellation

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, pipewire

I managed to get the microphone noise cancellation to work (in 20.04) a few months ago by adding the following to the `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
load-module module-echo-cancel source_name=noechosource sink_name=noechosink
set-default-source noechosource
set-default-sink noechosink
```

It added a second microphone option to the Ubuntu sound settings and worked great. But one day the second option had disappeared from my sound settings and I did not find a way to get it back. My `/etc/pulse/default.pa` had the same config in place.

I tried `sudo pulseaudio -k` to restart pulseaudio, but it gave me an error message about daemon not running. But `ps aux | grep pulse` shows that something was running.

Then I got frustrated and replaced pulseaudio with pipewire and upgraded to 22.04. In the beginning it gave terrible noice to my microphone but after adding noice and echo cancellation filters, it got better, but not as good as with pulseaudio (when it was working).

Does someone have ideas what to do? Some specific pipewire configs to use? Or how to fix the pulseaudio solution?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get the PulseAudio solution to work again. Installed PulseAudio and removed PipeWire according to [this guide](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/pipewire-replace-pulseaudio-ubuntu-2204/) (the same guide I used for installing PipeWire).

Then added back the:

```
load-module module-echo-cancel source_name=noechosource sink_name=noechosink
set-default-source noechosource
set-default-sink noechosink
```

Then reloading the user version of the pulseaudio:

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user reenable pulseaudio.service
systemctl --user reenable pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user start pulseaudio.service
systemctl --user start pulseaudio.socket
```

Some of those may be unnecessary, but at least it's working.