# Mic Noise Cancellation in 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, alsa, microphone, noise

My HP Pavilion comes with Bang & Olufsen sound, which has no Linux support. But I saw a lot of old topics here talking about PulseAudio, Pipewire etc. Wondering whether there is anything at all that can help me cancel the horrible noise disturbance in Ubuntu 22.04. It is gone in Windows 10 (dual boot) if I tick the "Mic Noise Cancellation" option in the Bang & Olufsen software.

I can use Bluetooth headphones and mic audio quality is a lot better. But it helps a lot if I can get the same noise-free recording with the in-built mic as well somehow.

Tried [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cFiaJFbPd8), didn't help much. The voice became too blunt.

[This one](https://www.informaticar.net/enable-noise-cancellation-in-ubuntu/) works. But not as good as the AI tools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microphone noise cancellation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452088/microphone-noise-cancellation). Note: 22.04 uses Pulseaudio by default. Pipewire became default [on 22.10](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/05/ubuntu-22-10-makes-pipewire-default)